# KMZ from QGIS won't display in Android Google Earth - raster images?

Tags: error, google-earth, android, kmz

Trying to get a KMZ working in the Google Earth Android app... works fine on Google Earth desktop... I think maybe it's because it has images in it?

Any ideas?

Error I get is:

> Error: 1 Parse Error at line 1, column 0:
>
> no element found

View KMZ [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ICLeL9r0EMZkxsZHpJb0dXNms/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Screenshot inside Google Earth App]

Comment: Are the images in the KML or (network) linked as reference? you can view the KML in an editor

Comment: Images are in the KMZ. Obviously the kmz is just a zip file that contains the kml (doc.kml) and the associated files. The KMZ opens fine on desktop.. all the coding appears to be fine? can't work out why it doesnt open on android app though?